# Calculating two persisted bootstrap-select values on .load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) -- I am multiplying the values of two select fields in a form, and changing the value of an input field to display the total -- after page load.

**How can I have the input field stay empty when just one or neither of the select fields are selected?**

Below code only works if both fields are selected.

1. When neither of the fields are selected, it calculates with the first values of both fields - output becomes $10.
2. When either one of the fields is selected, it multiplies the selected value with the first value of the non-selected field - output becomes 1 * selected value, or selected value * $10.

*PS. Reason I am using .load and not .change is that the fields are persisted with garlic.js*

```
<select class="price selectpicker form-control" id="price" name="price" title="Please choose price.." />
<option>$10</option>
<option>$20</option>
<option>$30</option>
</select>

<select class="multiply selectpicker form-control" id="multiply" name="multiply" title="Please choose multiplier.." />
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="total" id="total" readonly="true" />

$(window).on("load", function(){
var price = parseInt($('.price').val());
var multiply = parseInt($('.multiply').val());
var total = price * multiply;
if(total === ''){
$('#total').val('');
} else {
$('#total').val('$' + total);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the '**title**' attribute of '**bootstrap-select**', does not use a '**0**' value default option field. So the above code takes the value from the first selectable option when form is loaded.

To go around this issue:

1. Added the first default option with a zero value in the select tag.
2. Used the built in '[**show.bs.select**](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/#events)' to trigger an event when drop-down list is shown, and the built in '[**refresh**](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh)' method to remove it.

Complementary code:

```
$('.selectpicker').on('show.bs.select', function () {
$('.selectpicker').find('[value=0]').remove();
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
});

<select class="price selectpicker form-control" id="price" name="price" title="Please choose price.." />
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="10">$10</option>
<option value="20">$20</option>
</select>

<select class="multiply selectpicker form-control" id="multiply" name="multiply" title="Please choose multiplier.." />
<option value="0"></option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will helps you

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://garlicjs.org/garlic.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<form data-persist="garlic" method="POST">
<select class="price selectpicker form-control" id="price" name="price" title="Please choose price.." />
<option value="10">$10</option>
<option value="20">$20</option>
<option value="30">$30</option>
</select>

<select class="multiply selectpicker form-control" id="multiply" name="multiply" title="Please choose multiplier.." />
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="total" id="total" readonly="true" />

</form>
```

In script side

```
 <script>
    $(window).on("load", function(){
    calculate();

    $('.selectpicker').on('change',function(){
    calculate();

    })


    });
    function calculate()
    {
   var price = $('.price').val()?parseInt($('.price').val()):10;
var multiply =$('.multiply').val()? parseInt($('.multiply').val()):1;
    var total = price * multiply;
    if(total === ''){
    $('#total').val('');
    } else {
    $('#total').val('$' + total);
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: this was not what I was asking for, but turned out helpful in understanding how to combine the load and change function. thank you.

Comment: This change may works for you `var price = $('.price').val()?parseInt($('.price').val()):10;
var multiply =$('.multiply').val()? parseInt($('.multiply').val()):1;`